# Using Codemirror in Vim Mode

Tags: javascript, plugins, codemirror

I am having a little trouble making this thing up. I want to use Codemirror edit feature in Vim mode only, without any syntax highlighting. That is, if I click in the text area, it is converted in a similar text editor as shown on the demo page [VIM Demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/vim.html). Thanks!

**EDIT** :
If not Codemirror, Please tell me the method how can I convert the text area in which the user clicks to a VIM type edit area. I want to make it as a plugin, so that whenever I click on a text area on some page, it gives me a VIM like (not exactly vim) environment to edit. How should I go about the keybinding thing? Please help!

Comment: i don't see a question mark in your question.

Comment: I had added the question mark thing in comments. Sorry for that. Editing the main question.

Comment: ok, what have you tried so far? did you even read the docs?

Comment: Couldn't make the Codemirror thing to work for the textareas I click on page dynamically. I wrote custom naive code, a script which introduces onkeypress events to each text area attribute and call a function on each key press. Thereby I filter the keys and perform accordingly. I implemented basic Insert mode, navigation and replace thing. However to make it full featured, I wished to use Codemirror for that.. for which I am clueless. <br/> I read the API docs, but couldn't find the way I wish to implement it. Sorry for mine being dumb if I missed silly parts.

Answer (score 8):

CodeMirror takes care of all the key bindings (and key mapping for vim mode), so all you have to do is create an editor instance for the `textarea` at hand.

Check out `CodeMirror.fromTextArea()` on the docs, under the [section on static methods](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_static), to see how it's done.

You can also refer to the [vim bindings demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/vim.html) and simply take a look at the source. This is how the CodeMirror instance is initialized there:

```js
1  | CodeMirror.commands.save = function () {
2  |     alert("Saving");
3  | };
4  |
5  | var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
6  |     lineNumbers: true,
7  |     mode: "text/x-csrc",
8  |     keyMap: "vim",
9  |     showCursorWhenSelecting: true
10 | });
```

Let's take this apart, following line no':

- **1-3:** Assigning a handler for the *save* command, which maps to `:w` on vim key bindings. From the docs, on the key bindings section:

  > The values of properties in keymaps can be either functions of a
  >   single argument (the CodeMirror instance), strings, or false. Such
  >   strings refer to properties of the `CodeMirror.commands` object, which
  >   defines a number of common commands that are used by the default
  >   keybindings, and maps them to functions
- **4:** The sound of silence.
- **5:** Fetching the `textarea` element (denoted with `code` as its ID) from the DOM, and passing it to a static method that will create a CodeMirror instance based on that element.
- **6-9:** Setting various options:

  - **6:** Showing line numbers in the gutter.
  - **7:** Setting editor mode to C-like to highlight C code.
  - **8:** Assign the vim key bindings.
  - **9:** Well, showing cursor when selecting.
- **10:** Wrap it up.

In order for the editor mode and key bindings to work, the required scripts need to be loaded, so we'd wanna include those as well:

```html
<script src="../lib/codemirror.js"></script> <!-- main script -->
<script src="../addon/dialog/dialog.js"></script> <!-- addon for vim messages -->
<script src="../addon/search/searchcursor.js"></script> <!-- addon for vim messages -->
<script src="../mode/clike/clike.js"></script> <!-- mode for C-like languages -->
<script src="../keymap/vim.js"></script> <!-- key bindings for vim -->
```

Comment: Yeah! That's well good and I tried the above thing. I wished to know how can I implement it dynamically on all pages or websites I browse? That is, through an  Userscript or in form of a plugin, so that whatever page I'm browsing in, if I activate the Vim mode in any text area, it is transformed to a vim like text editor interface. I tried putting document.getActiveElement.id in place of what it is in your code, but it doesn't work (in static pages).